# Удалить последний символ в JSON файле

Tags: python, json

Есть файл содержащий список обьектов `json`

```
[
 {
   "123":123,
   "456":456
 },
 {
   "678":678,
   "1122":1122
 }
]
```

Требуется, при помощи [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) реализовать дозапись в файл `json` обьектов, но таким образом, чтоб это потом можно было считать.
Каких-либо готовых решений не нашел. Предполагал сделать таким образом:

1. Открыть файл.
2. Удалить последниq символ `]`
3. Добавить символ `,`
4. Дозаписать обьектов
5. Добавить символ `]`

Пример:

```
js_str = json.dumps(obj, ensure_ascii=False, indent=3)
f.write(bytes(js_str, encoding='utf-8'))
f.write(bytes(']', encoding='utf-8'))
```

В итоге предполагается получить что-то вроде:

```
[
 {
   "123":123,
   "456":456
 },
 {
   "678":678,
   "1122":1122
 },
 {
   "287":978,
   "5675":455676
 },
 {
   "125673":567123,
   "45643":45346
 }
]
```

Решение не должно загружать данные из файла, а просто дописывать новые.

Comment: Надо просто прочитать из файла старые данные. К прочитанным добавить новые и сохранить всё вместе в файл json.

Comment: Данные примеры, кстати, не являются валидным json

Comment: Спасибо. json поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Начем с того что у вас в примере не валидный json файл, если речь идет о валидном файле, тогда всё просто, вот смотрите, к примеру есть файл `data.txt` с таким контентом:

```
[{"123": 123, "456": 456}, {"1122": 1122, "678": 678}]
```

Вам нужно добавить в этот json данные, это делается всё просто через модуль `json`:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import json

# Имя нашего файла
json_file = 'data.txt'

# Открываем файл и заносим json в переменную
json_data=open(json_file)
data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

# Добавляем в json данные
data.append({"287":"978"})

# И сохраняем результат в этот же файл
with open(json_file, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)

# Выводим результат
print json.dumps(data)
```

На выходе получим файл с таким содержанием:

```
[{"123": 123, "456": 456}, {"1122": 1122, "678": 678}, {"287": "978"}]
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, не уточнил важную деталь: требуется не загружать все содердимое файла в память.